# Adding array as map reduce(MongoDb)

Tags: mongodb, join, mapreduce

I am trying to run map reduce for my data

```
LogData
[{
   "SId": 10,
   "NoOfDaya" : 9
  }
  {
    "SId": 11,
    "NoOfDaya" : 8
}]



  OptData 
 [ {
  "SId": 10,
  "CId": 12
 }

{
 "SId": 10,
 "CId": 13
}]
```

Note: SId is 10 in OpData

My MapReduce should return me data

1st Record

```
{
  "SId": 10,
  "NoOfDaya" : 9
  "1" : {
     "SId": 10,
     "CId": 12 },
  "2" : {
     "SId": 10,
     "CId": 13}
}
```

2nd Record

```
{
  "SId": 11,
  "NoOfDaya" : 8
}
```

Map-Reduce is combined on SId, since OpData is having SId =10 twice, 1st result is combination of these two (along with LogData).

Since SId = 11, is not present in OpData, 2nd result is showing only LogData (No OpData is combined).

Help me to combine it in this way.

Comment: Map/reduce doesn't do joins for you and you should not try to make it do joins for you. Design your documents to avoid joins when you can and do application-level joins otherwise. What is the purpose of the results you are trying to generate? How are you going to use them?

Comment: @wdberkeley: not always true. If you can see example like http://tebros.com/2011/07/using-mongodb-mapreduce-to-join-2-collections/

Comment: That's more than 3 years old.

Comment: @wdberkeley: Is it non relevant with today mongoDB? Do you have any solution?